# 'BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder)': no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to implement a MVVM in blazor I found on interesting [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/mvvm-pattern-in-blazor-for-state-management.aspx)

I want to go a step further and have my pages extend from an abstract class, but I am getting this error:

> Error CS0115  'ToDoTest.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder)': no suitable method found to override Pages_ToDoTest_razor.g.cs

Here is the code, abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyPage<T> : ComponentBase where T : IToDoViewModel
{
    public abstract T VModel { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        VModel.PropertyChanged += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            await InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                StateHasChanged();
            });
        };
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    async void OnPropertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        await InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        VModel.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChangedHandler;
    }

    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
    }
}
```

And, the page code behind is:

```
public partial class ToDoTest : MyPage<IToDoViewModel>
{
    [Inject]
    override public IToDoViewModel VModel { get; set; }

    override public void Dispose()
    {
        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong? can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct error is that the code-behind has a different base class than the razor-in-front class.

You can add this line to `ToDoTest.razor` :

```
@inherits MyPage<IToDoViewModel>
```

It will then compile.

Another issue

```
VModel.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChangedHandler;
```

this unsubscription will only work when you subscribe in OnInitialized with

```
VModel.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChangedHandler;
```

But I don't think such a literal transplantation of a WPF design pattern will work well in Blazor. You will get an (expensive) Render for each PropertyChanged(). Note that you don't (can't) use the propertyName.

Comment: Thank you Henk that worked! Just curious, can you suggest a better implementation of MVVM pattern or another pattern that works well on Blazor for the same purposes?

Comment: I would go for something simple, without PropertyChanged. Use simple passive ViewModels (just properties). The Blazor Component has to be more leading anyway, use it as a Controller.